# Rails 5: i18n for prompt in select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do i18n for prompt for this piece of code from my

*/views/media/medias/_newmedia.html.erb*

```
<%= f.select :media_type, Media::Medias.i18n_media_types.map { |w| [w[0].humanize, w[0]] },
{ prompt: I18n.t('mediatypes') }, {class:"form-control m-b"} %>
```

In my */config/locales/models/media/medias.en.yml* I have this:

```
en:
  media_medias_media_types:
    magazine: Magazine
    newspaper: Newspaper
```

and in */config/locales/views/media/medias.en.yml*

```
en:
  media:
    medias:
      mediatypes: Please select media type
```

First part where i18n is done for enums from Model is working, however **I cannot figure out how to i18n for prompt**.

I'd be happy for any hint to where should I be looking at. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try :

```
<%= f.select :media_type, Media::Medias.i18n_media_types.map { |w| [w[0].humanize, w[0]] }, :prompt => I18n.t('.mediatypes'), {class:"form-control m-b"} %>
```

Without the dot I18n.t('mediatypes') i18n is looking into the file /config/locales/en.yml

When you start with a dot I18n.t('.mediatypes') it's called lazy lookup. You should have a look at this [page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) section 4.1.4

Now i18n is looking for a translation into the file /config/locales/views/media/medias/en.yml as follow ( you must add a section for the partial and update the name of your file '/medias.en.yml' into '/medias/en.yml' )

```
en:
  media:
    medias:
      newmedia:
        mediatypes: Please select media type
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not help as it gives error: `translation missing: en.mediatypes`

Comment: it's better, no ? Cause you didn't mention it before. Now, can you share with us the /config/locales/en.yml

Comment: No, sorry - it's same result.

Comment: See my comment edit, please. You should have something like en: mediatypes: "Please select"

Comment: Thank you, in general it works as you say. In my view I had to do like this `{ prompt: (t'.mediasubtypes') }` and `/config/locales/views/media/medias/newmedia.en.yml` looks like you've put it.